# How to interpret Unix command?

Tags: awk, command-line

I have a command which looks like this:

```
cat PGC2.SCZ.1.dat | awk 'NR == 1 || $NF < 0.05/1783'
```

so this part I guess means skip the first line

```
awk 'NR == 1
```

but what does this refer to?

```
|| $NF < 0.05/1783'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NR` means "number of record" and refers to the line streamed to `awk`. (By default every new, not empty line is a new record. One can define a different record separator `RS`. Then the term `line` isn't correct here anymore.)

`NF` means "number of fields" and refers to the number of columns in the line. Due to the `$` before the `NF`, we are asking for the value in the last column. (NB: By default any run of spaces or tabs is used as a column delimiter aka field separator `FS`)

The `||` means "or".

So in summary your command will print out the first line in `PGC2.SCZ.1.dat` and all lines where the value in the last column is less then 0.05/1783.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you're learning *nix, this is an example of a "useless use of cat" (a famous trope in the *nix world). The `cat file | awk command` isn't needed here, you could just do `awk command file`.

Anyway, on to the awk. The default action when an expression evaluates to true in awk is to print the current line. `NR` is the current line number, so `NR == 1` will be true for the first line of the file. Then, awk splits its input into fields on whitespace (or anything else you choose using the `-F` option). The fields are then available as variables `$1`, `$2`, ... `$NF`, where `NF` is the number of fields. Therefore `$NF` is the contents of the last field.

Putting all that together, the expression `awk 'NR == 1 || $NF < 0.05/1783'` will be true on the first line and on any other line whose last field is less than `0.05` divided by `1783`.

You could write the same thing less idiomatically, but more clearly, as:

```
awk '{ 
        if(NR ==1 ){
            print
        } 
        else if ($NF < 0.05/1783){ 
            print 
        }
     }' PGC2.SCZ.1.dat
```